# How to run JavaScript code in PHP

Tags: php

The following HTML/JavaScript code inserts a background imag to a div without causing problems.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <title>to-forum.html</title>
  <script>
    function ChangeImage(param)
    { 
      return("http://localhost/images/greensilver.gif");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="logo" style = "height:400px; width:400px";> 
    <script>
      var xyz = ChangeImage();
      document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + xyz + "')";
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to run that JS script from a PHP code so I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <script>
    function ChangeImage(param)
    { 
      return("http://localhost/tlushim/images/greensilver.gif");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="logo" style = "height:400px; width:400px";> 
    <?php
      echo '<script>',
      'var xyz = ChangeImage"('" + 1 + "')";',
      'document.getElementById"('" + logo +"')".style.backgroundImage = "url('" + xyz + "')";',
      '</script>'
    ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With the second code I was less lucky/ This time the desired background image didn't show up, probably, because
I dont know how to run JS code from PHP.
Could anyone help me with that please?
Thanks

Comment: You can't run JS code in a PHP file. PHP runs on the server, JS runs on the client's browser. Couldn't you just add a `style="background-image: url(...); height: ..."` to your logo element?

Comment: Thanks. I'll not run JS from PHP anymore. This is a mistake !

Answer (score 0):

try using . for concatenation instead of , and + 
also escape the double quotes with \

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  echo '<script>',
  'var xyz = ChangeImage"('" + 1 + "')";',
                          ^
```

The single quotation mark I've marked above ends the PHP string. The double quotation mark following it is unexpected, and causes a syntax error.

Using PHP to echo out Javascript code is pointless here. If you insist, though, you can use herestring syntax to avoid the quoting issue:

```
<?php echo <<<EOS
<script>
    var xyz = ChangeImage();
    document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + xyz + "')";
</script>
EOS;
?>
```